# C# Regular expression replace question mark

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace question mark character `?` with text `Rs` if `?` is followed by numbers.

This is what I have tried. But not working.

```
 string str = "DFg sdfsdaf ?145 dfgsdf ?fg";
 str = str.Replace(@"\\?", "Rs");
 Console.WriteLine(str);
```

**Desired output:**

```
DFg sdfsdaf Rs145 dfgsdf ?fg
```

Please help.

Comment: you should use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx), not [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this too:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str,@"\?(?=\d+)","Rs");
```

I would recommend [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) read. The above pattern looks for `?` and checks if it is followed by `digit` one or more time then replaces `?` with `Rs`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\?(\d)", @"Rs$1")
```

It will match a literal question mark followed by a digit and replace it with `Rs` followed by that digit. Question marks followed by non-digits are left unchanged.

Example:

```
var str = "DFg sdfsdaf ?145 dfgsdf ?fg";
Console.Out.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"\?(\d)", @"Rs$1"));
```

Output:

```
DFg sdfsdaf Rs145 dfgsdf ?fg
```

Comment: hi..the output is coming DFg sdfsdaf Rs45 dfgsdf ?fg..... The first digit is removed...please help

Comment: @mhasan Make sure your replacement is `"Rs$1"` not just `"Rs"`. `$1` is replaced by the matched digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex

```
\\?((?:\d+))
```

Use Regex to handle this:-

```
  Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"\?((?:\d+))");
  str = oRegex.Replace(str, "Rs$1");
```

Comment: do you mean Regex.Replace? str.Replace searches for the characters, not for a regex.

Comment: @Default: You are right, it is Regex.Replace. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: You don't need the double escape in a raw string, also why are you using a non-capturing group inside a capturing group?